# Symfony 5 route named parameter constraint validator

Tags: symfony, validation, constraints

I have an API route as follows:

```
authors\{identifier}
```

I am looking to add a custom validator to make sure that the consumer of this endpoint is the same as that in the identifier (as identified by the token in the auth headers)

As this i a named route parameter I was hoping I could create a custom validator to verify that value, but I can't see which I need to use?

I am defining my validators in yaml format

Fields only seems to work on query string parameters, attributes isn't supported so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a validator issue, validators are (at least that's the usual case) for checking a form submit.
What you're looking for is a custom voter. I think the documentation is clear enough for your issue : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html